# How to use selected value by a user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to allow user to pick a dog food brand from a database. When he selects it, I want to use his submitted value and return him how many calories it has. I am stuck and don't know what to do next.

```
models.py

class DogFoodDry(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    calories_per_kg = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

That's urls.py after update:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index, name="index"),
path('dogs', views.results, name="results"),
path('add_dog', views.AddDogView.as_view(), name="add_dog"),
path('dogs/<int:id>', views.DogInfoView.as_view(), name="dog_info"),
path('<str:brand>/<str:name>', views.show_dry, name='form_food_selected'),
path('', views.show_dry, name='form_no_select'),]
```

That's forms.py after update:

```
class DogFoodDryForm(forms.Form):
    brand = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    calories_per_kg = forms.IntegerField()
```

That's views.py after update:

```
class DogInfoView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        dog = Dog.objects.get(id=id)
        rer = 70*dog.weight**0.75
        context = {'dog':dog, 'rer':rer}
        return render(request, 'dog_info.html', context)

def show_dry(request, brand=None, name=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DogFoodSelectionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dogfooddry =  DogFoodDry.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data["brand"])
            return redirect("dogfood:form_food_selected", dogfooddry.brand, dogfooddry.name)
    else:
        form = DogFoodSelectionForm()

    if brand and name:
        try:
            dogfooddry = DogFoodDry.objects.get(brand=brand, name=name)
        except DogFoodDry.DoesNotExist:
            dogfooddry = None
    else:
        dogfooddry = None

    context = {'form':form, 'dogfooddry': dogfooddry}

    return render(request, 'dogfood/dog_info.html', context)
```

That's dog_info.html after update

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" , value="Select">
</form>

{% if dogfooddry %}
<div>
    <strong>{{ dogfooddry.brand }} - {{ dogfooddry.name }}</strong><br/> {{ dogfooddry.calories_per_kg }} calories per kg.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You have calories in your template. You can try css display:none; <div class='hidden'>{{ food.calories_per_kg }}</div>. And when he select a brand, using jquery to show calories.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. Your question is vague on some details so I'm going to make some assumptions as we go. I named my app for this 'dogfood'.

`models.py` no major issues here, probably want to do yourself a favour and add a `def __str__` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#str)

```
from django.db import models

class DogFoodDry(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    calories_per_kg = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

You didn't supply a `urls.py` so I'm making one up here. Keep in mind there are other ways, but this is one way. We've got two paths, one to handle when you have a brand and name on the url like `/purina/kibbles` and another for when you don't. Both lead to the same view.

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'dogfood'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:brand>/<str:name>', views.show_dry, name='form_food_selected'),
    path('', views.show_dry, name='form_no_select'),
]
```

For your forms, you probably want an unbound form if you simply want to have a selection of brands, but this could be approached by someone else in another way. Here we are setting up the form, then on each instantiation of it loading up some choices (this makes sure your choices list gets reloaded as you add more brands). We put the choices into `brand_choices` by building a list of tuples with the pk and a string. I'd probably go another way with this in production simply as I don't like exposing the id's in this way but for demonstration purposes it's probably fine.

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms

from dogfood.models import DogFoodDry


class DogFoodSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        brand_choices = [(df.pk, f"{df.brand} | {df.name}") for df in DogFoodDry.objects.all()]

        self.fields['brand'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Select a brand',
                                                 choices=brand_choices,
                                                 )
```

I generally don't use the 'get' method on a form. It would probably be okay in this case, but I'm going to go with a function based view using a POST request on submit. Essentially, it sets up some `None` default values for `brand` and `name`, checks to see if this is a POST request, and if the form is valid (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid), finds the dog food selected by id in select box. It then would redirect to the named url path, supplying the expected variables for that url. If not a post, we load up an empty form. The `try` attempts to find an entry in the `DogFoodDry` model with this brand and name. This allows you to land directly on a url like `/mybrand/myname` with a get request and still work. We build up the context and render the template.

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from dogfood.forms import DogFoodSelectionForm
from dogfood.models import DogFoodDry


def show_dry(request, brand=None, name=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DogFoodSelectionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dogfooddry = DogFoodDry.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['brand'])
            return redirect('dogfood:form_food_selected', dogfooddry.brand, dogfooddry.name)
    else:
        form = DogFoodSelectionForm()

    if brand and name:
        try:
            dogfooddry = DogFoodDry.objects.get(brand=brand, name=name)
        except DogFoodDry.DoesNotExist:
            dogfooddry = None
    else:
        dogfooddry = None

    context = {'form': form,
               'dogfooddry': dogfooddry}

    return render(request, 'dogfood/dog_info.html', context)
```

Last but not least is your html template. I'll leave out the boilerplate html, and give you the bit you need. It has been a long time since I used a non crispy form form but you can see one way to do this here. After the form, we show the details for the food if we know it (which we will if they came in directly on an url with the brand and name in the url, or if we had picked a brand and got redirected in the view to the url with the brand and name). I recommend you read up on csrf_token in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

`dog_info.html`

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>

{% if dogfooddry %}
<div>
  <strong>{{ dogfooddry.brand }} - {{ dogfooddry.name }}</strong><br />
  {{ dogfooddry.calories_per_kg }} calories per kg.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great explanation! I think I do understand it, and there are some great things that will help me in future. 
I am quiet new with programming and sadly I have a small problem with implementing your guide. I think the issue is in my views and urls now

Comment: probably best to isolate your new issue and put into another question.

Comment: I did edit my previous question to the state of current code. Did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you are getting into a mix of class based views and function based views. Read https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/03/21/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views.html then decide which way you want to go.